# How to insert/append unstructured data to bigquery table

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

**Background**

I want to insert/append newline formatted JSON into `bigquery` table through python client API.

Eg:

```
{"name":"xyz",mobile:xxx,location:"abc"}
{"name":"xyz",mobile:xxx,age:22}
```

Issue is, all fields in a row are optional and there is no fixed defined schema for the data.

**Query**

I have read that we can use Federated tables, which supports autoschema detection.

However, I am looking for a feature, that would automatically detect schema from data,create tables accordingly and even adjust the table schema if any extra columns/keys appear in data instead of creating new table.

Would this be possible using python client API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use autodetect with BigQuery load API, i.e. your example using bq cli tool will look like following:

```
~$ cat /tmp/x.json
{"name":"xyz","mobile":"xxx","location":"abc"}
{"name":"xyz","mobile":"xxx","age":"22"}

~$ bq load --autodetect --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON tmp.x /tmp/x.json
Upload complete.

~$ bq show tmp.x
Table tmp.x

   Last modified          Schema          Total Rows   Total Bytes   Expiration  
 ----------------- --------------------- ------------ ------------- ------------ 
  16 Aug 08:23:35   |- age: integer       2            33                        
                    |- location: string                                          
                    |- mobile: string                                            
                    |- name: string                                              


~$ bq query "select * from tmp.x"

+------+----------+--------+------+
| age  | location | mobile | name |
+------+----------+--------+------+
| NULL | abc      | xxx    | xyz  |
|   22 | NULL     | xxx    | xyz  |
+------+----------+--------+------+
```

**Update:** If later you need to add additional fields, you can use schema_update_option to allow new fields. Alas it doesn't yet work with autodetect, so you need to provide new schema explicitly to the load API:

```
~$ cat /tmp/x1.json 
{"name":"abc","mobile":"yyy","age":"25","gender":"male"}

~$ bq load --schema=name:STRING,age:INTEGER,location:STRING,mobile:STRING,gender:STRING --schema_update_option=ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON tmp.x /tmp/x1.json
Upload complete.

~$ bq show tmp.x
Table tmp.x

   Last modified          Schema          Total Rows   Total Bytes   Expiration  
 ----------------- --------------------- ------------ ------------- -----------
  19 Aug 10:43:09   |- name: string       3            57                        
                    |- age: integer                                              
                    |- location: string                                          
                    |- mobile: string                                            
                    |- gender: string                                            


~$ bq query "select * from tmp.x"
status: DONE   
+------+------+----------+--------+--------+
| name | age  | location | mobile | gender |
+------+------+----------+--------+--------+
| abc  |   25 | NULL     | yyy    | male   |
| xyz  | NULL | abc      | xxx    | NULL   |
| xyz  |   22 | NULL     | xxx    | NULL   |
+------+------+----------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: This works well ,however when i load a different file which has some extra column(Eg:"Hobby":"def" ) ,it gives error saying There is no field "Hobby" in the table.So,any thoughts how to dynamically update table schema to avoid errors and prevent losing any data?

Comment: Please hold off for now, I will give you a good answer next week.

Comment: ok :),atleast , i assume that its not available in bq currently.

Comment: is it possible via API? I don't see any mentioning of something related to schema_update_option=ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION in documentation. I might be looking wrong direction. can you point me please

Comment: Everything that bq cli does is possible through API - in this case add the following to the "load" part of configuration:    "schemaUpdateOptions": [
    "ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION"
   ]

Comment: thank you Mosha! That was my guess. But still - it is not easily available in documentation!

Comment: what I found is that there is second option available - ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION (relaxing required field to nullable) and it is also applicable for query jobs for destination table. some limitations exist though. but still great to know!

Comment: Fair point - but this feature only rolled out today (this is why I waited with the answer), and the docs are lagging a bit - but they will be updated "soon".

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky,can't we update the schema with just providing the details of column to be added.

Comment: Not right now, it wants to see full new schema. Ideally in the future this will work nicely with autodetect, so there will be no need to provide schema for updated fields.

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky,can we create a temporary table for loading data which has extra columns ,bcoz. by doing that each time we could use '--autodetect' to force BQ to create a schema and then use the created new schema to update our main table and successfully load new data having extra columns.I explored and found that,BQ reads schema defined in a predefined format and not the schema generated by online tools.So, i assumed that my above approach will be good workaround for a schema free solution.Any thoughts on this?

Comment: A couple of years later - wondering if anyone has thoughts about how to solve this situation - I posted a new issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69478998/loading-dynamic-schema-json-files-into-a-bigquery-table-using-autodetect)