# IgnoreUnknownValues in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

**Background**

I have created a table with Fixed schema in Big Query. Now as a real time data which contains extra fields,but are optional in nature.
So,while loading 'JSON' files (that contain extra fields) I am getting error " xyz field doesn't exist".That's the natural response.

**Query**

However, i have came across a **property name "ignoreUnknownValues"**.

If **"ignoreUnknownValues=true"**,then all unknown fields are ignored.

I wonder,Is there a way around,by using this property,can we get an option to save the unknown fields in our table(if we wish to).

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Not possible with ignoreUnknownValues, but please wait until early next week for better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do it is to specify --schema_update_option=ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION and provide new schema explicitly to the Load API.

See example in [How to insert/append unstructured data to bigquery table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974176/how-to-insert-append-unstructured-data-to-bigquery-table)