# Loading JSON file into BigQuery table: Schema changes

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I am trying to load a json file into a BQ table. My schema looks something like:

```
{"_eventid": "1234", "Keywords":""}
{"_eventid": "4567", "Keywords":{"_text":"abcd"} }
```

From above, you can see that the schema changes for "Keywords." How do I deal with this? Using something like:

```
  {
   "name":"Keywords",
   "type":"record",
   "mode":"nullable",
   "fields": [
   {
    "name":"_text",
    "type":"string",
    "mode":"nullable"
   }
   ]
},
```

Only works for the second entry. For the first, I get the error:

```
Errors:
file-00000000: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up.    Rows: 1; errors: 1. (error code: invalid)
JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0 at file: file- 00000000. Flat value specified for record field. Field: Keywords;     Value: (error code: invalid)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Short Answer

Bigquery table is schema bounded. Whenever we try to ingest data which is not according to table schema we get error. In your case in the first record the value of `Keywords` is string but in the schema it is record with one nullable field which name is `_text`.

#### Workaround

You need to preprocess data before loading it to bigquery. If you have small json file you can write script and check if type of `Keywords` is record or string if it is string create the record first. So after preprocessing the file content would look like:

```
{"_eventid": "1234", "Keywords":{"_text": ""}}
{"_eventid": "4567", "Keywords":{"_text":"abcd"} }
```

According to your schema `Keywords` is nullable record. You can even ignore `keywords` which value is empty during preprocessing. After this step the input file would become.

```
{"_eventid": "1234"}
{"_eventid": "4567", "Keywords":{"_text":"abcd"} }
```

Comment: The JSON is around 30 GBs, so I'll have to think about the best way to implement this workaround.

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery now supports schema changes on load with

```
--schema_update_option=ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION
--schema_update_option=ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION
```

options. See [How to insert/append unstructured data to bigquery table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974176/how-to-insert-append-unstructured-data-to-bigquery-table) for more details and examples with JSON loading.

Comment: I have the latest Google SDK installed, but keep getting the error: FATAL Flags parsing error: Unknown command line flag 'schema_update_option' when attempting to using these flags.

Comment: Sorry - looks like bq CLI update is waiting for the next SDK release, but it is available on API now.

Comment: Still get the original error: "RuntimeError: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1.
JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0 at file: file-00000000. Flat value specified for record field. Field: Keywords; Value:" when running via the API.

Comment: Did you provide updated schema (with more columns) to the load command ? What is the job id of failed load - I can check it.

Comment: I'm loading a single test JSON file on my local machine with approximately 10 rows. 20% contain a flat structure for the field "Keyword", and the rest are nested (i.e. have"Keywords":{"_text":"abcd"} }). The job id is multiworldtesting-poc:job_6MVR46D3Q9XIuz0swhjtJn8KZKw

Comment: I think the only option -- at the moment -- is to apply a transformation to the json that converts "Keywords":"" to "Keywords":{"text":""}, as advised above.

Comment: I looked into it, but unfortunately couldn't see any other workaround, the schema change from flat field into record is not supported, so this transformation is probably the only thing you can do.

Comment: It's 2020 so I thought I'd give it an ask - is this supported in Python API?