# Is it possible to update schema while doing a load into an existing BigQuery table from DataFlow?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

Basically I am trying to do the equivalent of this CLI in DataFlow:

```
bq load  --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --schema_update_option=ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION --schema=users.schema.json projectid:dataset.users updates/users.json
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert/append unstructured data to bigquery table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974176/how-to-insert-append-unstructured-data-to-bigquery-table)

Comment: Got some code??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now `BigQueryIO` does not support this experimental option. I've filed [a JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-876) to support it.