# Loading dynamic schema JSON files into a BigQuery table using autodetect

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

This question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974176/how-to-insert-append-unstructured-data-to-bigquery-table) - but using the python API, and a couple of years later - and as the solution there is not complete, I thought it's best to open a new question.

---

I have a bunch of ndjson files, generated daily on GCS, which I would like to load to a BQ table.

example of a few lines from `file_1.json`:

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": [1,2,4], "d": "string"}
{"a": 1, "c": [2, 4], "d": "some_string"}
{"a": 1, "e": 4}
```

example of a  `file_2.json`:

```
{"a": 4, "e": 6, "f": {"g": 7, "h": "str"}}
{"a": 1, "c": [2, 4], "f": {"g": 5}}
```

Most fields are optional, and each file record in each file can theoretically contain any combination of fields (currently from a selection of about 50, but that will change and grow in the future). The content of a same-named field should (setting any bugs aside) contain the same data type.

I would like to load a set of files (all files from a certain day) to a BQ table with a schema that will consist of the union of all fields in the files, with a NULL value where a line has no key that corresponds to a field.

I am looking do to so without having a schema that needs to maintained.

My current attempt:

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
    create_disposition="CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
    autodetect=True,
    ignore_unknown_values=True,
    schema_update_option="ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION",
    source_format="NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON"
)
uri = "gs://my-bucket/test/*.json"

load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri,
    table_id,
    location="EU",
    job_config=job_config,
)

load_job.result()
```

uses `autodetect=True` to avoid specifying a schema explicitly, but since autodetect scans up to 500 rows from a single file - some fields might not be created at first.

I would expect that `schema_update_option="ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION"` ([ref here](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.SchemaUpdateOption.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.SchemaUpdateOption)) would do what I need, but it does not work.

Another option I have tried:

```
# Instead of wildcard, get blob list and convert to uris
blobs = storage_client.get_bucket(BUCKET).list_blobs(prefix=FOLDER)
uris = [f"gs://{BUCKET}/{blob.name}" for blob in blobs if blob.name.endswith(".json")]

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND", #Will append file by file
    create_disposition="CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
    autodetect=True,
    schema_update_option="ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION",
    source_format="NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON"
)

for uri in uris:
    load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
        uri,
        table_id,
        location="EU",
        job_config=job_config,
    )

    load_job.result()
```

This is less efficient, I would imagine - but regardless it also does not work - getting this error:

```
BadRequest: 400 Provided Schema does not match Table my-bucket:test.test_diff_schema. Cannot add fields (field: f)
```

Which again, I would imagine `schema_update_option="ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION"` would avoid - but it seems that it only works with predefined schema, not autodetect.

Any thoughts are welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In autodetect, BigQuery read a bunch of first line and try to detect the schema. After this first run, the schema is set and can't be changed during the whole ingestion. You can use the "ignore_unknown_values" option to skip the value that doesn't match the autodetected schema.

But it won't work as you wish. I know that BigQuery team work on a better JSON integration. For now, I can only recommend you to ingest the JSON as a string and to use the BigQuery JSON function to browse the documents.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know guillaume - that's good to know it's not really possible yet, and that it is on the roadmap. Meanwhile, I've switched to doing the ingestion with pyspark - but I'll take a look at ingesting as a string - though I'm hesitant to give up type inference on my data, which I assume happens. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery natively supports JSON data using the new JSON data type, with this we can ingest semi-structured JSON into BigQuery without providing a schema for the JSON data upfront. Hope this will solve your problem.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json-data